# Convert Gridview column from ID to String in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, controls

I currently have a Gridview that displays

TypeID , Name , Description.

I would like to display the actual type name instead of the TypeID in the gridview. I created this function that takes in the ID and returns the Name but I am having trouble using it. There are 15-20 different types so How do I convert the TypeID to a Type Name so that it is displayed when the Gridview is rendered.

```
protected string GetGenericTypeByID(int genericTypeID)
        {
            string genericTypeName;

            GenericType.Generic_TypeDataTable genericTypeNameDS = new GenericType.Generic_TypeDataTable();
            genericTypeNameDS = GenericBO.Get_GenericTypeByID(genericTypeID);

            genericTypeName = genericTypeNameDS[0]["Generic_Type_Name"].ToString();









            return genericTypeName;

        }
```

I thought I would be able to use the function in the ItemTemplate but it seems to be harder that I thought

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GetGenericTypeByID("Generic_Type_ID")")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks to Everyone who helped me solve this problem.
I ended up using the method below and it works perfectly.
GetGenericTypeByID( Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Generic_Type_ID")))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the 'bind/eval' and method call inside out.
See [Using Method inside a DataGrid or GridView TemplateField](http://yasserzaid.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/using-method-inside-a-datagrid-or-gridview-templatefield/)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=”Name”>
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href='<%# FormatUrl(Eval(”email1″).ToString())%>'><%# Eval(”fname”) %>,&nbsp;<%# Eval(”lname”) %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

With the 'FormatUrl' function being:

```
public string FormatUrl(string email)
{
    return “mailto:” + email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to a label tag? If not, Expanding on David HAust's answer try the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#GetGenericTypeByID(Eval(Generic_Type_ID))%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a read-only property on the row class that you're using to populate the grid, and get this property to return the results of your function.

Comment: This will only work if you're databinding to something like a List<T> where T is your row class. If you're databinding to a sql data set, then this won't be much help.